# Add multiple list items to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, list, combobox

How do I get all the testName present in the ListForTesting into the combobox? I have tried combobox_testType.ItemsSource = ListForTesting.testName but it doesn't work.

```
public class ManoeuvresID
{
    public string manName { get; set; }
    public int manID { get; set; }
}

public class TestID
{
    public string testName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IList<ManoeuvresID> manoeuvres { get; set; }
}

    HardCodedDatabase.TestID TestObjet = new HardCodedDatabase.TestID();
    TestObjet.manoeuvres = new List<HardCodedDatabase.ManoeuvresID>();
    HardCodedDatabase.ManoeuvresID man = new HardCodedDatabase.ManoeuvresID();
    man.manName="man1";
    man.manID = 2;
    TestObjet.manoeuvres.Add(man);
    List<HardCodedDatabase.TestID> ListForTesting = new List<HardCodedDatabase.TestID>();
    TestObjet.testName = "Steady State";
    ListForTesting.Add(TestObjet);
    TestObjet = new HardCodedDatabase.TestID();
    TestObjet.testName = "test2";
    ListForTesting.Add(TestObjet);
    combobox_testType.ItemsSource = ListForTesting;
```

Comment: You add same object `TestObjet` to list twice and also change it `testName`. I recommend you read about reference types first https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

Comment: @LayonezWronskey `TestObjet = new HardCodedDatabase.TestID();`

Comment: didn't mention that /:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to is add you object items using Items.Add or Items.AddRange
Example below

```
        foreach (var item in ListForTesting)
            comBox.Items.Add(item);
```

Add range

```
 comBox.Items.AddRange(ListForTesting);
```

Then you set, which properties within you class object, will be used to display and is you key

```
        comBox.DisplayMember = "testName";
        comBox.ValueMember = "TestId";
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. The first option worked like a charm, I just had to add item.testName.  Regarding the second option it does not show me the AddRange option?

Comment: The combo box within WPF, might be different to winforms. You get the AddRange on a ComboBox on winforms.
Never use it tho, always use the Add function as you have more control.  Reduce the black box of unknown!

Comment: So your thinking of Displaying the child ManName, within this list?
If not the child item will be accessible, when you take the selected item from the var item (TestID) combBox.SelectedItem.
item.manoeuvres.Select(x=>x.manName)

Comment: You may want to look at TreeView or create a Customer Control, which you have a combo box, containing a TreeView

Comment: Do you need the main parent element?
You could have the parent element, then On Selection Change,
Populate the Combo box or a new Combo box with the child list. The and display the ManName

Comment: MikeT maybe able to help more. As he says WPF have more functionality and you maybe able to do more with the combo box

Comment: Oh you definitely can do much more with a WPF Combo, as you have complete control over appearance, but until you get your head round how to weld that extra power and the different approaches you need to use to access them then its likely to just confuse

Answer (score 1):

have you tried linq

```
combobox_testType.ItemsSource = ListForTesting.Select(t=>t.testName);
```

another option would be to use the DisplayMemberPath

```
combobox_testType.ItemsSource = ListForTesting;
combobox_testType.DisplayMemberPath= "testName";
```

Comment: the same, with a list of ManoeuvresID do a select on manName or set DisplayMemberPath, if you want to do it from a list of TestID then you can do `ListForTesting.SelectMany(t=>t.manoeuvres ).Select(m=>m.manName)`

Comment: cool. this was what I was looking for  `combobox_testType.ItemsSource = ListForTesting[0].manoeuvres.Select(t=>t.manName);`

Comment: WPF is very powerful and almost certainly going to replace WinForms once its mature, but the idea it is based on is radically different to winforms, i'd suggest http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22980/WPF-A-Beginner-s-Guide-Part-of-n as a fairly good starting point for getting your head round it